# Change selected lines between layers in kicad

Tags: kicad

I have a very complex board profile in `DXF` format that I was able to import into pcbnew **version 5**. Now I have every line loaded on a single layer `dwgs.User`, I can move all of them to `edge.Cuts` by using `Edit -> Move and swap layer`, but how can I move only selected lines to `margin` layer for example? I know I can edit line by line and select its new layer, but as I've said it's a very complex profile with many line to be moved to `margin`, `f.cu`, `b.cu` and `f.fab`, so moving selected groups would be much easier since I have up to 5 variations of this board (in `DXF`), to convert to a kicad's template.

Will be happy with any tip!

Comment: Its not an answer to this question, but rather best practices to entirely avoid the problem of having to copy a complex edge cuts layer to other layers.  In the KiCad 5.1.5 release (and possibly others) there is an option (when generating plots) to "exclude PCB edge layer from other layers".  If you uncheck the box then the board outline will be included in the output of the other layers.  So by putting the board outline in the Edge.Cuts layer to begin with you can easily include it in the output for any other layer by checking a box (without having to copy or move it to another layer).

Answer (score 3):

2 years ago I've solved my issue by following the [response](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/411420/161912) from @Hermal, and for big projects I still believe that is the best way to go. But since them I've started to use a lot of python scripts to do this kind of task.

A valid answer to the original question would be:

```py
import pcbnew
board = pcbnew.GetBoard()
for drw in board.GetDrawings():
    if drw.IsSelected():
        drw.SetLayer(pcbnew[pcbnew.Edge_Cuts])
pcbnew.Refresh()
```

this will move **all** selected lines to the Edge_Cuts layer.

Want to set their width instead? Just replace the line `drw.SetLayer` to `drw.SetWidth(int(newWidthInMM * 1e6))`. With time and patience (due to *not good* documentation), is possible to have a lot of useful functions to be used in this extreme cases.

When you open the script console you will see the path for the startup script being loaded by it.

You should be able to edit this file and include your functions in there to have them easily available. something like:

```py
import pcbnew

def setLineWidth(w):
    "Set all selected graphical lines (not tracks) to new width"
    board = pcbnew.GetBoard()
    for drw in board.GetDrawings():
        if drw.IsSelected():
            drw.SetWidth(int(w * 1e6))  # internal value is in nano-meters
    pcbnew.Refresh()

def setLineLayer(l):
    """move all selected lines (not tracks), to new layer
    F_Cu, In1_Cu, In2_Cu, In3_Cu, In4_Cu, In5_Cu, In6_Cu, In7_Cu, In8_Cu, In9_Cu, In10_Cu, In11_Cu, In12_Cu, In13_Cu, In14_Cu, In15_Cu, In16_Cu, In17_Cu, In18_Cu, In19_Cu, In20_Cu, In21_Cu, In22_Cu, In23_Cu, In24_Cu, In25_Cu, In26_Cu, In27_Cu, In28_Cu, In29_Cu, In30_Cu, B_Cu, B_Adhes, F_Adhes, B_Paste, F_Paste, B_SilkS, F_SilkS, B_Mask, F_Mask, Dwgs_User, Cmts_User, Eco1_User, Eco2_User, Edge_Cuts, Margin, B_CrtYd, F_CrtYd, B_Fab, F_Fab"""
    board = pcbnew.GetBoard()
    for drw in board.GetDrawings():
        if drw.IsSelected():
            drw.SetLayer(pcbnew[l])
    pcbnew.Refresh()

def setReferenceSize(sr):
    "set ALL reference labels to new size"
    board = pcbnew.GetBoard()
    for mod in board.GetModules():
        mod.Reference().SetVisible(True)
        mod.Reference().SetTextHeight(int(sr * 1e6))
        mod.Reference().SetTextWidth(int(sr * 1e6))
        # mod.Value().SetTextVisible(True)
        # mod.Value().SetTextHeight(int(sv * 1e6))
        # mod.Value().SetTextWidth(int(sv * 1e6))
    pcbnew.Refresh()
```

To use these functions just open the console and call it. I.e. `setReferenceSize(.8)` will set all references sizes to .8mm (yes, you can do it from the edit menu, I know..., but with a script you may be able to create a button on the menubar to force the desired size every time a new bunch of parts are added to the board for example.

Any way, scripts are great, worth to waste some time to get used to it!

Comment: I had to use `drw.SetLayer(pcbnew.Edge_Cuts)` (without the subscript).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it. In the dxf file I'll make a reference shape out the board, like a small square and call it master dxf
Then I'll edit  and save as the dxf files and keep only margin lines, rename it board_margins.dxf and keep doing this for other layers.
Then import the dxf to it's layer. Here is where the square reference comes in handy to align all the layers. Make sure you dont change grid in between file imports.

Comment: the square reference could be an even greater help in upcoming version 5.1 as it will support end point snapping.